# Unable to add user to windown server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

On a windows 2012 server which has been registered on a domain, I want to create a user. However it gives me an error which says user doesn't exist!!! I know that. Who is going to create that?!!

Please see the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you are on an *add user to **this** computer* wizard. This means you are adding a local user profile, while your server is joined on a domain. That would be adding a profile for an existing domain user, and that's why it performs this lookup.

Instead, you should be adding a user to your *Active Directory (Users and Computers)*.